# how to add up the data with variable numbers in MySQL with Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to show the amount of data in columns users_count, then I add the result to 1 (users_coun +1). I use a table like this:

```
mysql> SELECT id, name, users_count FROM data;
+----+--------+-------------+
| id | name   | users_count |
+----+--------+-------------+
|  1 | Jogjas |          10 |
|  2 | madang |           0 |
|  3 | udan   |           0 |
+----+--------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if I select users_count on **id = 1**, the result is **10**.

the result I want is: **11**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only included SQL code, so not sure why you have tagged this as a python question.

Why don't you just do the addition in your SQL i.e. `SELECT id, name, users_count+1 as users_count FROM data;`

Answer (score 0):

use **Pymysql** or **(DAL)gluon tools** from web2py to access mysql in python.